# Using Pandas in Python: Splitting one column into three with possible blanks?

Tags: python, pandas, string, csv, split

Right now, I'm working with a csv file in which there is one column with a string.

This file is 'animals.csv'.

```
Row,Animal
1,big green cat
2,small lizard
3,gigantic blue bunny
```

The strings are either two or three elements long.

I'm practicing using pandas, with the `expand=True` option to separate the column into three. My ideal table would look like this:

```
Row,Size,Color,Animal
1,big,green,cat
2,small, ,lizard
3,gigantic,blue,bunny
```

But how can I deal with situations where one element is missing? In this example, "small lizard" has no color, but I still want to include it in the table. Here's the code I have so far.

```
import pandas as pd

file = 'animals.csv'

def copy_csv(file):

    filereader = pd.read_csv(file)
    filereader[['size', 'color', 'animal']] = filereader['Animal'].str.split(expand=True)
    filereader.to_csv('sorted' + 'animals.csv')
    
copy_csv(file)
```

I end up with this error, which I know is happening because one of the strings ("small lizard" only has two elements.

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Any suggestions for how to solve this?

Edit: I tried the suggestion below and tried this:

```
new = filereader['Animal'].str.split('\s', expand=True)
```

And get a little closer to the goal, but not quite:

```
Row,Size,Color,Animal
1,big,green,cat
2,small,lizard,None
3,gigantic,blue,bunny
```

Looks like I need to figure out a way to say "if there are only two elements, the middle element should be None".

Comment: The code is inconsistent with the CSV example. Is the header name `Animal` or `name`?

Comment: @adamius you're right, fixed that. It's Animal.

Comment: I am not sure a simple script could deal with that, except an AI. You put ```lizard``` in ```animal``` and not ```color``` because you already know like a human a ```lizard``` is not a ```color``` but an ```animal```. In other words the computer could put a blank in both options.